Saving MCQ Question Data to MongoDB from React Component and Retrieving on Another Page
I'm developing an MCQ (Multiple Choice Question) component in React.  Each question is stored in a JSON file with format below:
{
  "id": 1,
  "topic": "Topic 1",
  "question": "random question",
  "options": ["A. Hello", "B. Vincent van Gogh", "C. Pablo Picasso", "D. Michelangelo"],
  "correctAnswer": "A. Hello",
  "imageURL": "https://random.png",
  "explanation": "random text"
}

In my MCQ.jsx component, I have a "Save Question" button. When a logged-in user clicks this button, I want to:
Send the JSON data of the current question to my backend.
Store the question data in an array associated with the user's document in my MongoDB database.
Retrieve and display the saved questions on a separate page, MySavedQuestions.jsx.
I'm new to MERN stack. Also I would like to know the best approach to store my mcq questions data. Currently im storing in json files and calling in my component.
I have the following handleSaveQuestion function in MCQ.jsx:
   const user = useSelector((state) => state.user.currentUser); // Access the user from Redux state
    axios.defaults.withCredentials = true; // Ensure cookies are sent with requests
    
    const handleSaveQuestion = async (user) => {
        if (!user) {
            alert('You must be logged in to save a question.');
            return;
        }
    
        const userId = user._id; // Access the user ID directly from Redux state
    
        try {enter image description here
            const response = await axios.post(
                'http://localhost:3000/backend/user/save-question',
                { userId: userId, questionId: currentQuestionData._id } // Send both userId and questionId
            );
            if (response.data.message === 'Question saved successfully') {
                alert('Question saved successfully!');
            } else {
                alert(response.data.message);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error saving question:', error);
            alert('Failed to save question. Please try again.');
        }
    };

I'm unsure how to modify this function to pass the entire JSON question data from frontend, store it in the user's saved questions array in MongoDB, and then fetch it correctly on MySavedQuestions.jsx.
Images:
User database Mongodb
MCQ component
